# Keycloak configuration at runtime

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I successfully secured one of my applications using Keycloak. The procedure was to create a "keycloak.json" file and adding the security constraints in "web.xml" like described [here](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_java_adapter_config).

Now, since my application loads all configuration from an RDB table, managed by my application, and some of that information is about the realm, I want to centralize that information.

The idea would be to either:

1. Have the "keycloak.json" and inject Keycloak values obtained at servlet runtime from the RDB table.
2. Load the configuration at servlet runtime after RDB table configuration load.

I also want to add a configuration parameter to the RDB table to enable\disable Keycloak validation when needed.

Is this even possible? If it is could you please point me to some examples?

Comment: I guess this isn't possible (or not straight forward, at least). Keycloak.json is parsed when application starts, you have no way to guarantee it does after your DB connector sets up. What you could do, however, is to stablish that values in your server environment (it is explained in the link you've given).

Comment: Yes, I've seen that option. The problem is since my application can belong to multiple solutions (I consider them realms), each solution which I deploy using Wildfly container images, would need to have a different standalone.xml configuration. Despite working, it's not the most elegant way to go...

Comment: Are you using docker to deploy it? Then you could easily achieve that using environment variables instead of having to change the file.

Comment: Yes, I am using Docker for deployment but not for development. For development, I'm using a Wildfly local installation. Environment variables would be great for deployment but not so great for development...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically create the configuration using the KeycloakConfigResolver, see the [multi-tentant keycloak example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/multi-tenant).

Comment: Yes, from what I've seen before posting this question, multi-tenancy  was the best option. I was hoping that there was something else, but it seems like not. I'll try that approach and provide some feedback ASAP

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm... Still there is one more thing I would like, which is to add a configuration variable to my application that enables\disables Keycloak. How can I do this?

Comment: But why would you need that?

Comment: It might be useful to disable Keycloak for development reasons. Let's imagine my Keycloak instance is down or I just don't have communication with it, and urgently need to call one of my application's APIs. How can I do that without commenting my security rules defined in "web.xml"?

Comment: You can always copy the certificates and create a client which signes its own tokens.

Comment: But in general I think you should accept that if keycloak is down, your service is down. Designing for the 0.01% percent use-case is not very good use of your time.